# Graph implementation (does graph include all vertices?)

Tags: prolog

Trying to implement following predicate, which takes on input

- list of lists - one list = one tested graph T (as edges)
- graph G itself (as edges)

and tests whether T includes all of the vertices of G. If it does(true) should return it. Basically it's list filtering.

What I have so far is:

```
covb([],G).
covb([H|R],G) :-
    isItCov(G,H), covb(R,G).

isItCov([],H).
isItCov([V-W|R],H) :-
    vertex(V,H),
    vertex(W,H), 
    isItCov(R,H).

vertex(V,[V-_|G]).
vertex(V,[_-V|G]).
vertex(V,[_|G]):- vertex(V,G).
```

For `covb([[a-c,c-b,c-d]],[a-b,a-c,a-d,c-d,b-c])` works fine(`true`). For covb([[a-c]],[a-b,a-c,a-d,c-d,b-c]) works fine too (`false`). I got an issue while I call it with multiple lists like `covb([[a-c,c-b,c-d],[a-c]],[a-b,a-c,a-d,c-d,b-c]).` which should work only for the first one. 
I actually got two questions -

1. Why does it work for one list only?
2. I want to *return* items of lists of lists which passed the condition and returned `true` (that's the filtering part). How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your program has a number of singleton variable warnings. **Do not ignore singleton variable warnings.** They can hide real bugs. Also, since more experienced Prolog users here know that programs with singleton variable warnings are not even worth running, they will (a) just see the warnings and decide that they are no longer interested in trying to help you, or (b) fix the warnings on their side, but then by definition they will be working on a program that is no longer the program you posted!

Now for your questions.

> Why does it work for one list only?

It's really not clear what you are asking here, or just above with "`covb([[a-c,c-b,c-d],[a-c]],[a-b,a-c,a-d,c-d,b-c]).` which should work only for the first one."

This query *does* fail:

```
?- covb([[a-c,c-b,c-d],[a-c]],[a-b,a-c,a-d,c-d,b-c]).
false.
```

This comes down to testing each of the two lists:

```
?- isItCov([a-b,a-c,a-d,c-d,b-c], [a-c,c-b,c-d]).
true .

?- isItCov([a-b,a-c,a-d,c-d,b-c], [a-c]).
false.
```

The first list does cover the graph, while the second doesn't. Overall, your definition of `covb/2` is written to succeed if *all* lists cover the graph. This is not the case, so your `covb/2` query fails.

Was this what you wanted to know?

> I want to return items of lists of lists which passed the condition and returned true (that's the filtering part). How should I do that?

You could see if your Prolog's documentation has something for the word "filter". On SWI-Prolog you can do this:

```
?- apropos(filter).
true.
```

This will point you to the `include/3` predicate, which seems to do what you want:

```
?- include(isItCov([a-b,a-c,a-d,c-d,b-c]), [[a-c,c-b,c-d],[a-c]], Covers).
Covers = [[a-c, c-b, c-d]].
```

If you want to write a filter predicate for your concrete application, it might look something like this:

```
graph_covers(_Graph, [], []).
graph_covers(Graph, [Nodes|NodesRest], Covers) :-
    (   isItCov(Graph, Nodes)
    ->  Covers = [Nodes|CoversRest]
    ;   Covers = CoversRest ),
    graph_covers(Graph, NodesRest, CoversRest).
```

This is similar to your predicate, it just adds an extra argument to collect those node lists for which `isItCov/2` succeeded. If it did not succeed, it continues with a list *not* containing that current node list.

```
?- graph_covers([a-b,a-c,a-d,c-d,b-c], [[a-c,c-b,c-d],[a-c]], Covers).
Covers = [[a-c, c-b, c-d]] ;
false.
```